# How to replace value of variable within function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and I am likely over complicating this. I am having problem with values in variables within a function not being replaced. Instead, it seems to just be adding the new value to it. With this function, if you select 1 or 2, it is supposed to perform certain actions, if you select anything else, it is supposed to say that is not an option and have you try again. Here is the output if I select a wrong option before selecting a valid option:

```
Select Option

[1] Option 1
[2] Option 2

You selected Option 1
1
9
7
6
```

So instead of replacing the value of my variable to 1 and clearing previous values, it seems to just add to it. Here is my code:

```
def testfunc():

    testvar = input('Select Option\n\n[1] Option 1\n[2] Option 2\n\n    >')
    if testvar in ('1', 'Option 1', 'option 1'):
        print("\nYou selected Option 1")
    elif testvar in ('2', 'Option 2', 'option 2'):
        print("\nYou Selected Option 2")
    else:
        print("\n\nThat is not an option, please select another option")
        testfunc()
    print(testvar)

testfunc()
```

If I could have someone explain why its storing multiple values and how I can prevent this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You are printing the value after you call the function again, so its printing the last value. Put the print function _after_ the `testvar = input()` line.

Comment: That was exactly it. Very simple. If you put in a answer I will mark it as the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can answer your own question :)

Comment: @Stephen, that is _so much_ not the correct answer :-) There is absolutely zero reason to use recursion here and you should change your structure to be a loop instead.

Comment: @paxdiablo: it is ok to use recursion here (a thousand invalid attempts before stackoverflow is more than enough for a human).

Comment: It's okay to wash your car with a toothbrush as well but that doesn't make it a _good_ idea :-) I tend to favour simplicity over complexity in cases where the latter is not necessary.

Comment: @paxdiablo: you could have said the exact same *literally* thing if I said that a `while` loop is ok here. The comment about cars is meaningless. btw, often recursive solutions are easier to understand e.g., recursive quicksort is much simpler than its iterative variant.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I wouldn't have said that because `while` is what I suggested in my answer :-) You need _some_ sort of loop since you want to repeat an action. Your point on quicksort is a good one however recursive sorts are good because you generally _have_ to return to an earlier point because the data there may have changed. In this case, there is no requirement to save the bad information hence iteration is more natural than recursion. A better analogy would be a tree _search_ rather than sort, since you need not return to an earlier stater, and iteration is just fine for that case.

Comment: Still, I won't labour the point, we may have to agree to disagree (amicably of course).

Comment: @paxdiablo: btw, the recursive call in the fixed recursive solution is in the tail-call position. We could add [tail-call elimination decorator](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tail-call-optimization) and the solution becomes iterative. Either way the solution is iterative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you use *recursion* to go back and get another value (the call to `testfunc()` within `testfunc()` itself).

If you enter an invalid value, it will call the function again, saving its current position (before the `print`) so it can return to there.

Then, when you finally enter a *good* value, it will eventually unwind the stack, printing out the invalid ones as you go.

You are better off using a loop for this sort of validation, something like:

```
def testfunc():
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        testvar = input('Select Option\n\n[1] Option 1\n[2] Option 2\n\n    >')
        if testvar in ('1', 'Option 1', 'option 1'):
            print("\nYou selected Option 1")
            ok = True
        elif testvar in ('2', 'Option 2', 'option 2'):
            print("\nYou Selected Option 2")
            ok = True
        else:
            print("\n\nThat is not an option, please select another option")

    print(testvar)

testfunc()
```

Comment: read your answer after the initial comment on my question, and I appreciate the explanation as well as the example very much.